# Adding item to sound menu

Tags: unity, 13.10, indicator-sound

I made a little Python app that posts the song I'm listening to on Twitter. I added its .desktop to the sound menu alright, but it shows up with the Prev - Play/Pause - Next controls (just like any media player).

I added it by copying its .desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/ and (in dconf-editor) added it to /com/canonical/indicator/sound/interested-media-players/ too.

Is there any way to display it just as a simple menu item (without the unnecessary and nonfunctional control buttons), like the "Sound settings" at the bottom of the menu? I tried looking through the .desktop specification, but I couldn't find any hints.

Comment: Why do you want your item in the sound menu if you don't want also volume control?  Perhaps you want a standalone indicator rather than shoe-horn into the volume/sound indicator.